# How do you find the url for a node.js express site on a VPS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, vps, ovh

I recently purchased a VPS from OVH for the hosting of my discord bot. It has a stats.json page that I need to have another site GET to, but I can't seem to find my VPS's express site.

I'm trying to access it from my `vpsXXXXXX.vps.ovh.ca`, but I get the error: `This site can’t be reached`. I have the following on my main code:

```js
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});
app.get("/", (request, response) => {
  response.sendStatus(200);
});
app.get('/stats', function(request, response) {
response.sendFile(__dirname + "/stats.json");
});
```

And even with this code, I get no response from the VPS's URL.

I'd want to have my `glitch.me` site to be able to GET the data from the `stats.json`, but I can't seem to find or figure out a way to get a URL for my VPS.

Does anyone know how to connect a URL or use the VPS URL?

Thank You!

Codingpro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to listen. Set the environment port instead

```
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Online on port ${port}!`))
```

Answer (score 0):

**I figured out my issue:**

I had forgotten to add the `app.listen()` to the code. Here is what I added to fix it:

```js
var port = 3000

/*
* Set your server's port. This made mine vpsXXXXXX.vps.ovh.ca:3000. 
* HTTP standard port: 80
* HTTPS standard port: 443
*/

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Online on port ${port}!`))
```